# Responsive table bootstrap three columns on desktop one on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this table

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-borderliness table-product">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-4">Column 1</td>
                <td class="col-4">Column 2</td>
                <td class="col-4">Column 3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-4"><ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li>
</ul></td>
                <td class="col-4"><ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li>
</ul></td>
                <td class="col-4"><ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li>
</ul></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

The desktop version is working perfectly, but on mobile, I want to show only one column and the user can scroll, in my case theres so much text in one column and it may have rich text and lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bootstrap 4 if you want to specify for small screens, use col-* instead of col-xs-* refer to [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options)
so in your example you need to do this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-borderliness table-product">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-12 col-md-4">Column 1</td>
                <td class="col-12 col-md-4">Column 2</td>
                <td class="col-12 col-md-4">Column 3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-12 col-md-4"><ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li>
</ul></td>
                <td class="col-12 col-md-4"><ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li>
</ul></td>
                <td class="col-12 col-md-4"><ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, repudiandae, dolorem quos nisi debitis quibusdam amet labore blanditiis iusto eos ipsum iure quisquam molestias perspiciatis delectus pariatur magni eum nesciunt.</li>
</ul></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```